# What does the word 「ぽやっと」 mean?

Tags: colloquial-language, manga, onomatopoeia

It is in a dialogue said by an old man to a young man during their fighting.

> さあ　**ぽやっと**見てねえで　打ってきなっ わしを力石と思って　力いっぱい打ちこんできなっ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「ぽやっと」, in this context, would mean "***absentmindedly***".

It is in the form of 「***onomatopoeia + と***」, which functions adverbially.

「ぽやっと見{み}てねえで」, therefore, means "***Stop looking (at me) absentmindedly and ~~***."

Answer (score 0):

”力石”ときたら、間違いなく漫画の「あ〇たの〇ョー」の登場人物です。（〇（まる）は特定を避けるために日本では一般的によく使う。）私は読んだことがない漫画ですが、テレビＣＭなどによく使われることで、年齢がある程度上の（例えば昭和生まれあたり）大体の方がこの漫画を知っています。この漫画は個性の強いキャラクターがきっと魅力の一つの筈です。
　一般的に登場人物の言葉遣いをわざと標準の言葉から外すことは漫画ではよくあることですし、思春期の中学生が友達の間でふざけてそのように話すことはよくあります。
　標準語かつ丁寧な言い方に直しますと「さあ　ぼけっと見てないで　打ってきなさい　私を力石と思って　力いっぱい打ち込んできなさい」になります。
　「ぽやっ」とは一般的に使われているかは私もわかりませんが、キャラクターづくりのために擬音語「ぼけっと」を「ぼやっと」などで組み合わせて作ったと想像することもできると思います。「ぽ」の音はかわいいイメージがあるので（例えば「ヒヨコはぽよぽよしている」）、「ぽやっと」していると言われた登場人物が若いとか、純朴であるとかの性質を発話者が持っていることを暗に示すことができるような気がしますので、このような言葉遣いが漫画に載っているのではないでしょうか。